# How to create a half Cylinder in Three js?

Tags: three.js

I´m very new to three js and I want to create a half Cylinder as roof.

```
 var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(100,100,150);
 var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
 var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
 scene.add(cylinder);
```

This is the Basic Cylinder but unfortunately I couldn´t find an specific answer to a half cylinder yet. 
Is it possible to create this with vertices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last 2 params of CylinderGeometry constructor allows this. For example:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(100,100,150, 8, 1, false, 0, Math.PI);
```

0 is the start angle and Math.PI is the end angle; i.e. half of a circle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still doesn´t work for me. I´m using the website       http://gamingjs.com/ice/      Is there something that I could be still missing?

Comment: Looks like that site is using ThreeJS r52. The additional params for CylinderGeometry seem to have been added in later versions.